# paginate_links with select option

Tags: pagination

**This function output :**

```
<<NEXT [SELECT] PREV>>
```

**i need this :**

```
<option value="link/page1">Page 1</option>
<option value="link/page2">Page 2</option>
```

*how do I convert this function to this?*

```
function yorumlariSayfala ( $args = array() ) {
global $wp_rewrite;

if ( ! is_singular() )
    return;

$page = get_query_var('cpage');
if ( !$page )
    $page = 1;
$max_page = get_comment_pages_count();
$defaults = array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $max_page,
    'current' => $page,
    'echo' => true,
);
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
    $defaults['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_permalink()) . $wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base . '-%#%', 'commentpaged');

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
$page_links = paginate_links( $args );

if ( $args['echo'] )
    echo $page_links;
else
    return $page_links;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet for archive navigation with previous and next link along with the select dopwdown. Select will contain the list of all pages and page url as value of option. `onChange` is used to redirect page when select option is changed. You can use following code and modify as per your need.

```
function wpso_custom_archive_navigation() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
        return;
    }
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    // Previous link.
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) {
        printf( '%s', get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous' ) );
    }

    echo '<select onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $max ; $i++ ) {
        echo '<option value="' . esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $i ) ) . '" ' . selected( $i, $paged ) . '>';
        echo 'Page ' . $i;
        echo '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    // Next link.
    if ( get_next_posts_link() ) {
        printf( '%s', get_next_posts_link( 'Next' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to modify it and I failed. :(

Comment: What happened after you called this function?